# Adding a User Control in code-behind in WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm having trouble adding a user control to my interface (either in xaml or via the code behind). I've had a look around the forum, but have not been able to find anything.

To create the UC, all I did was go File --> Add --> User Control

In my code behind, I'm trying to add the control to my dock panel on a button click. I've tried handling the click by both the window and the dockpanel but to no avail.

Here is the code I am using to add the UC to the dockpanel in the code behind:

```
Company myControl = new Company();
theDock.Children.Add(myControl);
DockPanel.SetDock(myControl, Dock.Right);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: 1. This question is poorly worded; the title makes it sound like the problem was with adding the usercontrol to your project (or possibly to a parent), but it sounds like you're doing both of those just fine. Please edit your question to make it clearer what the question is. 2. If you're having trouble handling a click event, you need to show your click-handling code. (And if you're handling it from a parent, you should also give us some idea of what parent elements are between the button and the handler.)

Comment: Also as a matter of fact, if you want to dynamically add/remove objects, I'd advise you to use an `ItemsControl` so you can easily add an object to the `ItemsSource` and let it be updated without having to work on visual objects